# How to auto increment the key of a hashmap using collectors and stream in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am new to Java 8:  `Streams` and `Collectors` classes.

I am reading a file whose content need to be saved in a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>` where its `<keys>` are the line numbers of the files and its `<values>` are the content at each line, respectably.

Here, I want to use the `Stream` concept but I am not able to use `Collectors.toMap` to auto-increment the `<keys>`, which need to be saved in the `LinnkedHashMap` object. Instead of that I am getting exceptions.

Following is the code which i am trying:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Integer count = 0;

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader( Paths.get( fileName ) )) {
    // br returns as stream and convert it into a List
    list = br.lines().collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

list.forEach( System.out::println );

Map<Integer, String> fileNumWithContentMapper = list.stream()
        .collect( Collectors.toMap( n->n+1,s1->s1));
```

Comment: You want to create a HashMap with keys, consecutive from 0 - n, depending on how may entries? What is the use of a HashMap, that an Array or ArrayList doesn't already have? Its keys are exactly that

Comment: What are the exceptions you are getting? could you please update your question with that information?

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to to this. But here I will explain my way:

#### 1. Set the size of a `IntStream` object.

First, whenever you have a `List<E>` of objects (i.e. `E` could be `String`, `Integers`, `Objects`, etc.) you can convert it into a `Map<Integer, E>` by using the `IntStream` class. This class is a sequence of primitive int-valued elements that supports sequential and parallel aggregate operations. This means is like a huge counter. If we already have a counter we need to put some limits and the `IntStream.range(int start, int end)` method will help us. This method will returns a sequential ordered `IntStream` from `start` (inclusive) to `end` (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1. So if you want to create a  `IntStream` with the size of our `List` use this:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 4, 3);
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, numbers.size);
```

#### 2. Prepare a `Stream` object based on the `IntStream` object.

Now, we have a counter of the size of your `List<E>`, but we need a `Map<Integer, E>`. Well, now we gonna use the `IntStream.boxed()`. This method returns a `Stream` consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an `Integer`. This is a `Stream<Integer>`. We are almost done.

```java
Stream<Integer> streamBoxed = stream.boxed();
```

#### 3. Convert the `Stream` object to a `Map` object

Finally, we can create the map, using the `Stream.collect()` method. This method performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream. This reduction will be complicated if we didn't have the help of `Collectors.toMap()` method. This collector can be used to collect Stream elements into a Map instance. To do this, we need to provide two functions: `keyMapper` and `valueMapper`. The `keyMapper` will be used for extracting a `Map` key from a `Stream` element, and `valueMapper` will be used for extracting a `<value>` associated with a given `<key>`. For our example, we will use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. The `keyMapper` will the values of the `steamBoxed` stream we can extract, using `i -> i`, and the `valueMapper` should be the values of the `numbers` list we will get those, using `i -> numbers.get(i)` like this:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> result = streamBoxed.collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.get(i)))
```

#### 4. Combine all the steps

These three parts can be combined together in this simple code:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 4, 3);

Map<Integer, Integer> result = IntStream
        .range(0, numbers.size); // IntStream 
        .boxed(); // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.get(i))) // Map<Integer, Integer>
```

Also, you will find that some authors prefer to use `Function.identity()` method as a `keyMapper`, and `numbers::get` lambda expression  as `valueMapper`. **Why they use those expressions?** Just for preference. The `Function.identity()` method will always return the same instance. So, using `Function.identity()` instead of `i -> i` might save some memory. However, `i -> i` is more readable than `Function.identity()` but because creates its own instance and have a distinct implementation class consume more memory. The `::` lambda expression is just a method reference capture.

#### But, how can I apply this to my solution?

Well, like this:

```java
final List<String> list;

...
// list initialization;
list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
...

Map<Integer, String> fileNumWithContentMapper = IntStream
        .range(0, list.size()) // IntStream 
        .boxed() // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> list.get(i))); // Map<Integer, String>
```

Alternative

```java
final List<String> list;

...
// list initialization;
list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
...

Map<Integer, String> fileNumWithContentMapper = IntStream
        .range(0, list.size()) // IntStream 
        .boxed() // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), list::get)) // Map<Integer, String>
```

Comment: well explained with proper example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `IntStream.range`:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> list.get(i)));
```

Another option would be using the `LineNumberReader` API.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    list.forEach( System.out::println );

    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Map<Integer, String> fileNumWithContentMapper = list.stream()
                .collect( Collectors.toMap( n->i.incrementAndGet(),s1->s1));

    System.out.println(fileNumWithContentMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `List` like below:

```
List<String> list =  Arrays.asList("Vishwa","Ram","Mohan","Sohan");
```

Now you want **Output** Like **below**:

```
0  Vishwa
1  Ram
2  Mohan
3  Sohan
```

---

```
public class Someclass{
static int j=0;
static int count(int de){
    return de++;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<String> list =  Arrays.asList("Vishwa","Ram","Mohan","Sohan");
        Map<Integer,String> map;
        map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s->{count(j);return j++;}, Function.identity()));
        map.forEach((k,v)-> {
                         System.out.print(k+"  ");
                         System.out.println(v);
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream.of("A", "B", "C").collect(TreeMap<Integer, String>::new
    ,(map, element) -> map.put(Optional.ofNullable(map.lastEntry()).map(e -> e.getKey() + 1).orElse(1), element)
    ,(m1, m2) -> {})
    .forEach((i, e) -> System.out.println(i + " " + e));
```

Prints:

```
1 A 
2 B
3 C
```