# IllegalStateException: "Duplicate key" for Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, java-8

> Reference Question:
>   [Numbers which constitute the Maximum sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219407/numbers-which-constitute-the-maximum-sum)

I was writing a program which would print the elements which have constituted to the maximum sum.
I have been able to pass through any random scenario but when my maximum sum constitutes of two sets, my code fails.

**My code:**

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TestCases = reader.nextInt();
        reader.nextLine();
        String[] output = new String[TestCases];
        String sss = "";
        String ddd = "";

        for (int k = 0; k < TestCases; k++) {
            int noofELements = reader.nextInt();
            reader.nextLine();
            String[] al = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
            List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(al).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Ideone mm = new Ideone();
            String maxi = mm.maximumm(numbers, ddd);
            sss = sss.concat(maxi);

        }
        System.out.println(sss);

    }

    public String maximumm(List<Integer> numbers, String sss) {
        int toIndex = 3, fromIndex = 0;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while (toIndex < numbers.size()) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> map =
                IntStream.range(fromIndex, toIndex).mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, numbers.get(i)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
            // find max of sublist
            int maxOfSub = numbers.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
            //update indexes
            fromIndex = map.get(maxOfSub) + 2;
            toIndex += fromIndex;

            result.add(maxOfSub);
        }
        int lastMax = numbers.subList(fromIndex, numbers.size()).stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
        if (lastMax > 0) {
            result.add(lastMax);
        }
        result = result.stream().sorted(Integer::compareTo).collect(Collectors.toList());
        //System.out.println(result);
        sss = sss.concat(result.toString().replace(", ", "").replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
        return sss;
        //  return result.stream().reduce(0,Integer::sum);
    }
}
```

For example when i am giving a input of `4 5 4 3` , then maximum sum of non adjacent elements is 8 , which would be made from `4 4` or `5 3`.

My full code is working fine, just that i am not able to get both results in my final result.

My Error Log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate
>   key 0     at
>   java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
>     at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1254)   at
>   java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
>     at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)    at
>   java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
>     at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>     at Ideone.maximumm(Ideone.java:47)  at Ideone.main(Ideone.java:27)

Error is pointed to this line:    `result.add(maxOfSub);`

Any help would be nice :)

Comment: When you said **"non adjacent elements"** do you mean two or more or only two?

Comment: I believe the coding challenge allows to add many numbers, as long as no 2 of them are adjacent. Not that it matters for the exception.

Comment: It matters, the exception is because he is inverting the a `submap(k, v) -> submap(v, k)` and cuz `v` should be unique, in this case there are two numbers `4`. If he wants to get only the sum of two non adjacent elements the implementations will change.

Comment: There is, by the way, no need for the `.mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, numbers.get(i)))` step in your operation. You can simply use `IntStream.range(fromIndex, toIndex).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.get(i)));` instead. It would also work as `IntStream.range(fromIndex, toIndex).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),numbers::get));`. Of course, it doesn’t help you with the exception. There are duplicates, hence, you have to decide what should happen with the duplicates.

Comment: related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this error is that you have a duplicated `<key>` when you call the `Stream.collect()`. Remember, this method performs mutable reduction operation on the stream elements. So when your call:

```java
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Here, you are defining the `<keys>` of a `Map` object as the `<values>` of  `Entry<index, values>` defined by the `Stream.mapToObj()` method. Now, when in your data test you have `4, 5, 4, 3`, it means, you are trying to create the `<key>` for the number `4` twice. Therefore, you got this `IllegalStateException`.

#### But how can I fix this?

Very simple, just switch the definition of your `Map` object from `<values, indexes>` to `<indexes, values>` in the `Stream.collect()` call. **How can I do this?** Well, just replace the `Map.Entry::getValue` with `Map.Entry::getKey` and vise versa, like this:

```java
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Also, there is better equivalent by using the `IntStream.boxed()` method. This method returns a `Stream` consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an `Integer`. For me this is the best way to convert a `List` object into a `Map` object like this:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream
        .range(fromIndex, toIndex)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.get(i) > 0 ? numbers.get(i) : 0));
```

Notice that I'm using this expression `i -> numbers.get(i) > 0 ? numbers.get(i) : 0` to assign the `<values>` of the `Map` object. **Why are you doing this?** Because, we need to track remove the negative numbers so I replaced them with zero. The `Stream.filter()` method is an alternative, but the `Map` object will not contain the filtered elements.

However, this modification will affect how you are updating your indexes, because now the map values are the `<values>` and not `<indexes>` as shown in this line:

```java
fromIndex = map.getOrDefault(maxOfSub, toIndex - 1) + 2;
```

To fix this you just need convert get the `<index>` from the corespondent `<value>` like this:

```java
fromIndex = IntStream
        .range(fromIndex, toIndex)
        .filter(i -> map.get(i).equals(maxOfSub))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(toIndex - 1) + 2;
```

#### Alternative solution

Now, the above information will only solve the `IllegalStateException`. However, I found that there is another error. If I use this array of numbers `1, 9, 1, 7, 7, 5, 4, 1, 6`, the max sum of non adjacent numbers should be `[9 + 7 + 5 + 6] = 27` but your code got `[9 + 7 + 6] = 22`. So I tried to find a solution for this here:

```java
public class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
//        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 4, 3);
//        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 9, 1, 7, 7, 5, 4, 1, 6);
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(-1, 7, 8, -5, 4, 9, -2, 3);

        String sss = "";
        String ddd = "";
        Ideone mm = new Ideone();

        List<List<Integer>> maxi = mm.findMaxSumNonAdjacentStream(numbers, numbers.size());
        System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(maxi));

    }

    public List<List<Integer>> findMaxSumNonAdjacentStream(List<Integer> numbers, int size)
    {
        int fromIndex = 0;

        Map<Integer, Integer> maxSumMap = IntStream
                .range(fromIndex, size)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> numbers.get(i) > 0 ? numbers.get(i) : 0));

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> indexMap = IntStream
                .range(fromIndex, size)
                .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, Collections.singletonList(numbers.get(i))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        maxSumMap.replace(1, Math.max(numbers.get(1), numbers.get(0)));

        List<Integer> maxValList = maxSumMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() > 1)
                .map(entry -> {
                    int index = entry.getKey();
                    int prevOne = index - 1;
                    int prevTwo = index - 2;
                    int prevValOne = maxSumMap.getOrDefault(prevOne, 0);
                    int prevValTwo = maxSumMap.getOrDefault(prevTwo, 0);

                    int maxVal = Math.max(prevValOne, prevValTwo + entry.getValue());
                    boolean exclude = prevValOne > (prevValTwo + entry.getValue());

                    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (prevValOne > 0 && exclude) {
                        elements = new ArrayList<>(indexMap.get(prevOne));
                    } else if (prevValTwo > 0 && !exclude) {
                        elements = new ArrayList<>(indexMap.get(prevTwo));
                    }

                    if (!exclude) {
                        elements.add(entry.getValue());
                        elements = elements.stream().sorted(Integer::compareTo).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    }

                    maxSumMap.replace(index, maxVal);
                    indexMap.replace(index, elements);

                    return index;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Integer max = maxValList
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(v -> v)
                .max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

        int lastMax = maxValList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(-1);
        Integer maxVal = maxSumMap.get(max);

        List<Integer> result = maxSumMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(maxVal))
                .map(i -> i.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Predicate<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> containMaxList =
                mapEntry -> result.contains(mapEntry.getKey());

        return indexMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(containMaxList)
                .map(i -> i.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing explanation, i am very much thankful to you.

Comment: @tromu check this answer for more information about [the `Stream.collect()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047522)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build an inverse map from a map with duplicate values, which causes duplicate keys. You must avoid this.

A map like

```
{0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 3}
```

cannot be inverted to

```
{4: 0, 5: 1, 4: 2, 3: 3}
```

because what would map.get(4) then be? 4 or 0?

The error happens in

```
// 1)
IntStream.range(fromIndex, toIndex)
    // 2)
    .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, numbers.get(i)))
    // 3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Map.Entry::getValue, 
                 Map.Entry::getKey));
```

- 1) First you create an int range stream (0, 1, 2, 3)
- 2) then you create a Stream of `SimpleEntry ((0: numbers[0]), (1: numbers[1]), (2: numbers[2]))`
- 3) then you try to invert this as a map:

  {numbers[0]: 0, numbers[1]: 1...}

Comment: What should be the approach to curb this ?

Comment: No simple fix, you need to solve the problem differently than you wanted to. Solving the programming exercise is outside the scope of Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some duplicates `<keys>` in you values. Look:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map =
                IntStream.range(fromIndex, toIndex).mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, numbers.get(i)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

#### How to solve it

You exchange the `key-value` in code `Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey)`,so you got duplicate error.